# GGTS 3.2 console timout failure on new Grails project

Tags: eclipse, grails, console

I tried upgrading to GGTS 3.2 on windows7 64bit and java 7.0.21.  running on works pc with a proxy config enabled in internet settings

i create a new project in a new workspace.  I then try and run the console for the app.

the console fires up and you can use for ~60 seconds.  After that the sts ide throws a timeout error and the console is killed

error in log looks like this :

```
!ENTRY org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2013-06-18 22:08:15.103
!MESSAGE Problem executing: console
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe (18 Jun 2013 22:06:14)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.

See details for the output produced so far.

If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time limit in the Grails preferences page.

See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.launch.SynchLaunch$LaunchResult.getCoreException(SynchLaunch.java:168)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.launch.SynchLaunch.synchExec(SynchLaunch.java:57)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GrailsExecutor.synchExec(GrailsExecutor.java:131)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GrailsCommand.synchExec(GrailsCommand.java:169)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.ui.internal.inplace.GrailsLaunchUtils$1.run(GrailsLaunchUtils.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Contains: ------System.out:-----------
 | Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Packaging Grails application.
| Compiling 1 source files.....
Contains: ------System.err:-----------

Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 60000 milliseconds
!SUBENTRY 1 org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 4 2013-06-18 22:08:15.103
!MESSAGE The command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe (18 Jun 2013 22:06:14)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.

See details for the output produced so far.

If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time limit in the Grails preferences page.

See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch
!SUBENTRY 2 org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2013-06-18 22:08:15.103
!MESSAGE ------System.out:-----------
 | Loading Grails 2.2.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Packaging Grails application.
| Compiling 1 source files.....
!SUBENTRY 2 org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2013-06-18 22:08:15.103
!MESSAGE ------System.err:-----------

Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 60000 milliseconds
```

There was something like this is the sts/ggts forum which claimed it had been fixed in 3.3m2.  and might have been to do with pref>groovy>grails>launch  - keep running flag - however i enebaled and diabsled this and it made no difference

i tried installing 3.3m2 and tried the same - new workspace - new project.  I run the console, 60 seconds later i get a timeout buty the console stays up - error now reads

```
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Packaging Grails application.
| Compiling 1 source files.....
Contains: ------System.err:-----------

!SUBENTRY 1 org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 4 2013-06-18 23:27:11.110
!MESSAGE Command terminated with an exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jps": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified (see details for partial output)
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jps": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessStackTracer.exec(GrailsProcessStackTracer.java:104)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessStackTracer.getGrailsProcessId(GrailsProcessStackTracer.java:72)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsProcessStackTracer.getStackTraces(GrailsProcessStackTracer.java:92)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsClient.executeCommand(GrailsClient.java:381)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.client.GrailsCommandExecution.execute(GrailsCommandExecution.java:85)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.LongRunningProcessGrailsExecutor.synchExec(LongRunningProcessGrailsExecutor.java:82)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.commands.GrailsCommand.synchExec(GrailsCommand.java:169)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.ui.internal.inplace.GrailsLaunchUtils$1.run(GrailsLaunchUtils.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
!SUBENTRY 2 org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2013-06-18 23:27:11.110
!MESSAGE ------System.out:-----------
 Loading Grails 2.2.2
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Packaging Grails application.
| Compiling 1 source files.....
!SUBENTRY 2 org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2013-06-18 23:27:11.110
!MESSAGE ------System.err:-----------
```

Any one else had this and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The "Execute Grails Command" function wasn't designed to support persistent processes. It worked previously by chance, but no longer does.

The recommended way to execute long-running grails processes in Eclipse/STS/GGTS is to configure an eclipse run configuration to execute the long-running grails commands. (Run -> Run Configurations...)